# P5.js instance: export to SVG

Tags: svg, export, p5.js

A p5.js sketch is creating a plot that I would like to export as SVG.

The plot is not static: it must be modified (in the demo by clicking on the circle) and then saved by pressing the `Save SVG` button.

P5.js alas doesn't provide `beginDraw()` and `endDraw()` as the standard Processing.

I am using https://github.com/zenozeng/p5.js-svg/, as described in this blog: https://makeyourownalgorithmicart.blogspot.de/2018/03/creating-svg-with-p5js.html

Saving a static SVG (without user interaction) is easy: uncommenting `p.SVG` and `p.save()` the code works:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/zenozeng/p5.js-svg/releases/download/v0.5.2/p5.svg.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <script>

        let colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "lime", "green", "blue", "fuchsia"];
        let idx = 0;

        let sketch = function (p) {

            p.setup = function () {
                p.createCanvas(400, 400); // (400, 400, p.SVG);  <--------------
                p.noLoop();
            };

            p.draw = function () {

                p.background("white");
                p.fill(colors[idx]);
                p.stroke("black");
                p.strokeWeight(3);
                p.ellipse(200, 200, 200,200);

                // p.save();   // <-----------------------------------
            };

            p.mousePressed = function() {
                if (p.dist(p.mouseX, p.mouseY, 200,200) < 100) {
                    idx++;
                    idx %= colors.length;
                    p.redraw();
                }
            }
        };

        let myp5 = new p5(sketch, "my_image");

        let save_svg = function() {
            // ????   <------------------------------
        }


    </script>

    <div id="my_image"></div>

    <button onclick="save_svg()">Save SVG</button>

</body>
</html>
```

How can the user modify the plot and then save the final version only upon request?
Is this possible using `p5.js-svg` or any other library?

I also tried https://github.com/gliffy/canvas2svg but I could not have it working at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution: not the cleanest one, but it works.
A bug concerns fonts: if you load a font, inside the SVG it is rendered as geometry. This means the SVG can be huge if there is a lot of text and slow to visualize.

I create a double canvas: a normal one and a SVG. The latter is put into a hidden div. Whenever I am done playing with it, I call the SVG save function that will use the latest calculated parameters (they must be shared between the two, of course).

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/zenozeng/p5.js-svg/releases/download/v0.5.2/p5.svg.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <script>

        let colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "lime", "green", "blue", "fuchsia"];
        let idx = 0;

        let sketch = function (p) {

            p.setup = function () {

                if (p.type === "SVG") {
                    p.createCanvas(400, 400, p.SVG);
                }
                else if (p.type === "NORMAL") {
                    p.createCanvas(400, 400);
                }
                else {
                    alert("don't know which canvas to create")
                }
                p.noLoop();
            };

            p.draw = function () {
                p.background("white");
                p.fill(colors[idx]);
                p.stroke("black");
                p.strokeWeight(3);
                p.ellipse(200, 200, 200,200);

                p.fill("black");
                p.noStroke();

                p.textStyle(p.NORMAL);
                p.text("test", 100, 100);

                p.textStyle(p.BOLD);
                p.text("bold", 200, 200);

                waiting = false;
            };


            p.mousePressed = function() {
                if (p.dist(p.mouseX, p.mouseY, 200,200) < 100) {
                    idx++;
                    idx %= colors.length;
                    p.redraw();
                }
            };

            p.save_canvas = function() {
                p.draw();
                p.save();
            }
        };

        cvs = new p5(sketch, "my_image");
        cvs.type = "NORMAL";

        svg = new p5(sketch, "hidden_div");
        svg.type = "SVG";


    </script>

    <div id="my_image"></div>
    <div id="hidden_div" style="display:none"></div>

    <button onclick="svg.save_canvas()">Save SVG</button>

</body>
</html>
```