# Histogram based on image as vector graphic

Tags: image-processing, processing, histogram, p5.js, histogram2d

I would like to transform histograms based on images to vector graphics.

This could be a start:

```js
function preload() {
  img = loadImage("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/36/Cirrus_sky_panorama.jpg/1200px-Cirrus_sky_panorama.jpg");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  background(255);
  img.resize(0, 200);
  var maxRange = 256
  colorMode(HSL, maxRange);
  image(img, 0, 0);
  var histogram = new Array(maxRange);
  for (i = 0; i <= maxRange; i++) {
    histogram[i] = 0
  }

  loadPixels();

  for (var x = 0; x < img.width; x += 5) {
    for (var y = 0; y < img.height; y += 5) {
      var loc = (x + y * img.width) * 4;
      var h = pixels[loc];
      var s = pixels[loc + 1];
      var l = pixels[loc + 2];
      var a = pixels[loc + 3];
      b = int(l);
      histogram[b]++
    }
  }
  image(img, 0, 0);
  stroke(300, 100, 80)
  push()
  translate(10, 0)
  for (x = 0; x <= maxRange; x++) {
    index = histogram[x];

    y1 = int(map(index, 0, max(histogram), height, height - 300));
    y2 = height
    xPos = map(x, 0, maxRange, 0, width - 20)
    line(xPos, y1, xPos, y2);
  }
  pop()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.1/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

But I would need downloadable vector graphic files as results that are closed shapes without any gaps between. It should look like that for example:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 399.84 200"><polygon points="399.84 200 399.84 192.01 361.91 192.01 361.91 182.87 356.24 182.87 356.24 183.81 350.58 183.81 350.58 184.74 344.91 184.74 344.91 188.19 339.87 188.19 339.87 189.89 334.6 189.89 334.6 185.29 328.93 185.29 328.93 171.11 323.26 171.11 323.26 172.55 317.59 172.55 317.59 173.99 311.92 173.99 311.92 179.42 306.88 179.42 306.88 182.03 301.21 182.03 301.21 183.01 295.54 183.01 295.54 179.04 289.87 179.04 289.87 175.67 284.21 175.67 284.21 182.03 278.54 182.03 278.54 176 273.5 176 273.5 172.42 267.83 172.42 267.83 179.42 262.79 179.42 262.79 182.03 257.12 182.03 257.12 183.01 251.45 183.01 251.45 178.63 245.78 178.63 245.78 175.21 240.11 175.21 240.11 182.03 234.86 182.03 234.86 150.42 229.2 150.42 229.2 155.98 223.53 155.98 223.53 158.06 217.86 158.06 217.86 167.44 212.19 167.44 212.19 162.58 206.52 162.58 206.52 155.98 200.85 155.98 200.85 158.06 195.18 158.06 195.18 167.44 189.51 167.44 189.51 177.46 183.84 177.46 183.84 166.93 178.17 166.93 178.17 153.69 172.5 153.69 172.5 155.87 166.82 155.87 166.82 158.05 161.78 158.05 161.78 155.63 156.11 155.63 156.11 160.65 150.84 160.65 150.84 146.59 145.17 146.59 145.17 109.63 139.49 109.63 139.49 113.67 133.82 113.67 133.82 61.48 128.15 61.48 128.15 80.59 123.11 80.59 123.11 93.23 117.44 93.23 117.44 97.97 111.76 97.97 111.76 78.07 106.09 78.07 106.09 61.66 100.42 61.66 100.42 93.23 94.75 93.23 94.75 98.51 89.7 98.51 89.7 85.4 84.03 85.4 84.03 111.03 78.99 111.03 78.99 120.57 73.32 120.57 73.32 124.14 67.65 124.14 67.65 23.48 61.97 23.48 61.97 0 56.3 0 56.3 120.57 50.63 120.57 50.63 167.01 45.38 167.01 45.38 170.83 39.71 170.83 39.71 172.26 34.03 172.26 34.03 178.7 28.36 178.7 28.36 175.36 22.69 175.36 22.69 170.83 17.02 170.83 17.02 172.26 11.34 172.26 11.34 178.7 5.67 178.7 5.67 103.85 0 103.85 0 200 399.84 200"/></svg>
```

Has anyone an idea how to program that? It doesn't necessarily need to be based on p5.js, but would be cool.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/zenozeng/p5.js-svg as described in [P5.js instance: export to SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50156951/p5-js-instance-export-to-svg)?

Comment: @ggorlen Yeh, I could use that, thank you. But I guess first the gaps between the lines should be removed.

Comment: Essentially you are dealing with a rounding error.  You want to make sure that the width of each bar in the histogram is a whole number, so you need your canvas to be divisible by the number of bars.

Comment: But there are other issues in your code with the way that you are iterating over the array from `loadPixels()`.  You are not looking at the correct pixels.  You are getting some of the white space.  I can maybe fix this but not right now as it's not a quick one-liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Closing Gaps

In order to have a gapless histogram, you need to meet the following condition:

```js
numberOfBars * barWidth === totalWidth
```

Right now you are using the p5 `line()` function to draw your bars.  You have not explicitly set the width of your bars, so it uses the default value of `1px` wide.

We know that the `numberOfBars` in your code is always `maxRange` which is `256`.

Right now the total width of your histogram is `width - 20`, where `width` is set to `400` by `createCanvas(400, 400)`.  So the `totalWidth` is `380`.

```js
256 * 1 !== 380
```

If you have 256 pixels of bars in a 380 pixel space then there are going to be gaps!

We need to change the `barWidth` and/or the `totalWidth` to balance the equation.

For example, you can change your canvas size to `276` (`256` + your `20`px margin) and the gaps disappear!

```js
createCanvas(276, 400);
```

However this is not an appropriate solution because now your image is cropped and your pixel data is wrong.  But actually...it was already wrong before!

### Sampling Pixels

When you call the global `loadPixels()` function in p5.js you are loading all of the **pixels for the whole canvas**.  This includes the white areas outside of your image.

```js
for (var x = 0; x < img.width; x += 5) {
    for (var y = 0; y < img.height; y += 5) {
        var loc = (x + y * img.width) * 4;
```

It is a 1-dimensional array, so your approach of limiting the `x` and `y` values here is not giving you the correct position.  Your `loc` variable needs to use the width of the entire canvas rather than the width of just the image, since the pixels array includes the entire canvas.

```js
var loc = (x + y * width) * 4;
```

Alternatively, you can look at **just the pixels of the image** by using `img.loadPixels()` and `img.pixels`.

```js
img.loadPixels();

for (var x = 0; x < img.width; x += 5) {
  for (var y = 0; y < img.height; y += 5) {
    var loc = (x + y * img.width) * 4;
    var h = img.pixels[loc];
    var s = img.pixels[loc + 1];
    var l = img.pixels[loc + 2];
    var a = img.pixels[loc + 3];
    b = int(l);
    histogram[b]++;
  }
}
```

The pixel values are always returned in RGBA regardless of the `colorMode`.  So your third channel value is actually the `blue`, not the `lightness`. You can make use of the [p5.js `lightness()` function](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/lightness) to compute the lightness from the RGBA.

### Updated Code

The actual lightness histogram looks dumb because 100% dwarfs all of the other bars.

```js
function preload() {
  img = loadImage("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/36/Cirrus_sky_panorama.jpg/1200px-Cirrus_sky_panorama.jpg");
}

function setup() {
  const barCount = 100;
  const imageHeight = 200;

  createCanvas(400, 400);
  background(255);
  colorMode(HSL, barCount - 1);

  img.resize(0, imageHeight);
  imageMode(CENTER);
  image(img, width / 2, imageHeight / 2);
  img.loadPixels();

  const histogram = new Array(barCount).fill(0);

  for (let x = 0; x < img.width; x += 5) {
    for (let y = 0; y < img.height; y += 5) {
      const loc = (x + y * img.width) * 4;
      const r = img.pixels[loc];
      const g = img.pixels[loc + 1];
      const b = img.pixels[loc + 2];
      const a = img.pixels[loc + 3];
      const barIndex = floor(lightness([r, g, b, a]));
      histogram[barIndex]++;
    }
  }

  fill(300, 100, 80);
  strokeWeight(0);

  const maxCount = max(histogram);

  const barWidth = width / barCount;
  const histogramHeight = height - imageHeight;

  for (let i = 0; i < barCount; i++) {
    const count = histogram[i];
    const y1 = round(map(count, 0, maxCount, height, imageHeight));
    const y2 = height;
    const x1 = i * barWidth;
    const x2 = x1 + barWidth;
    rect(x1, y1, barWidth, height - y1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.1/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

But the `blue` channel histogram looks pretty good!
[image]

```js
function preload() {
  img = loadImage("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/36/Cirrus_sky_panorama.jpg/1200px-Cirrus_sky_panorama.jpg");
}

function setup() {
  const barCount = 100;
  const imageHeight = 200;

  createCanvas(400, 400);
  background(255);

  img.resize(0, imageHeight);
  imageMode(CENTER);
  image(img, width / 2, imageHeight / 2);
  img.loadPixels();

  const histogram = new Array(barCount).fill(0);

  for (let x = 0; x < img.width; x += 5) {
    for (let y = 0; y < img.height; y += 5) {
      const loc = (x + y * img.width) * 4;
      const r = img.pixels[loc];
      const g = img.pixels[loc + 1];
      const b = img.pixels[loc + 2];
      const a = img.pixels[loc + 3];
      const barIndex = floor(barCount * b / 255);
      histogram[barIndex]++;
    }
  }

  fill(100, 100, 300);
  strokeWeight(0);

  const maxCount = max(histogram);

  const barWidth = width / barCount;
  const histogramHeight = height - imageHeight;

  for (let i = 0; i < barCount; i++) {
    const count = histogram[i];
    const y1 = round(map(count, 0, maxCount, height, imageHeight));
    const y2 = height;
    const x1 = i * barWidth;
    const x2 = x1 + barWidth;
    rect(x1, y1, barWidth, height - y1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.1/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Linda's excellent answer(+1), you can use [p5.svg](https://github.com/zenozeng/p5.js-svg) to render to SVG using p5.js:

```js
let histogram;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(660, 210, SVG);
  background(255);
  noStroke();
  fill("#ed225d");
  // make an array of 256 random values in the (0, 255) range
  histogram = Array.from({length: 256}, () => int(random(255)));
  //console.log(histogram);
  
  // plot the histogram
  barPlot(histogram, 0, 0, width, height);
  // change shape rendering so bars appear connected
  document.querySelector('g').setAttribute('shape-rendering','crispEdges');
  // save the plot
  save("histogram.svg");
}

function barPlot(values, x, y, plotWidth, plotHeight){
  let numValues = values.length;
  // calculate the width of each bar in the plot
  let barWidth  = plotWidth / numValues;
  // calculate min/max value (to map height)
  let minValue  = min(values);
  let maxValue  = max(values);
  // for each value
  for(let i = 0 ; i < numValues; i++){
    // map the value to the plot height
    let barHeight = map(values[i], minValue, maxValue, 0, plotHeight);
    // render each bar, offseting y 
    rect(x + (i * barWidth), 
         y + (plotHeight - barHeight), 
         barWidth, barHeight);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/p5@1.3.1/lib/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/p5.js-svg@1.0.7"></script>
```

(In the [p5 editor](https://editor.p5js.org/george.profenza/sketches/ZGBSiyVJU) (or when testing locally) a save dialog should pop up.
If you use the browser's Developer Tools to inspect the bar chart it should confirm it's an SVG (not `<canvas/>`))